# Fetching data from youtube using jquery api is not working

Tags: jquery, youtube

I'm trying to fetch some youtube video data, using the jquery api get() and getJSON(), but I got not responses.

```
$.get('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/eGfAj9ZJymo',
    function(data) {
        alert('data loaded');
    });
```

I also try with getJSON function, and I got the same result, none.

but I tested this example  http://jsfiddle.net/FzejW/, and did work.

Comment: have you included the jQuery framework in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice, the [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/FzejW/) that you gave has a `callback=?` parameter in its query string. That triggers jQuery to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) instead of JSON.

The reason your code doesn't work is probably due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy): You cannot fetch data from another origin (protocol + subdomain + domain + port) using XHR. But you can do JSONP simply because JSONP is done through `<script>` tags and are not subject to the same origin policy.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details.

Try including `callback=?` in your request URL and see if it helps...